# Listen for variable change in helper class

Tags: firebase, flutter, asynchronous, controller, future

I am trying to build a login screen for my app using firebase. I have the login functionality working fine, but I am having an issue getting some error text to display if the login fails.

This is the code for the authentication helper class:

```
class AuthenticationService {

  final FirebaseAuth _firebaseAuth;

  String errorText = "";

  AuthenticationService(this._firebaseAuth);

  Stream<User> get authStateChanges => _firebaseAuth.authStateChanges();

  Future<void> signOut() async {
    await _firebaseAuth.signOut();
  }

  Future<String> signIn({String email, String password}) async {
    try {
      await _firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
      return "Signed in";
    }
    on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      errorText = e.message;
      return e.message;
    }
  }

  Future<String> signUp({String email, String password}) async {
    try {
      await _firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
      signIn(email: email, password: password);
      return "Account created";
    }
    on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      errorText = e.message;
      return e.message;
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the code for my SignIn widget:

```
class SignIn extends StatefulWidget {
  final TextEditingController emailController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController passwordController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _SignInWidgetState();
}

class _SignInWidgetState extends State<SignIn> {
  final TextEditingController errorController = TextEditingController();
  bool _isErrorContainerVisible = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Sign In"),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          TextField(
            controller: widget.emailController,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              labelText: "Email",
              hintText: "example@gmail.com",
              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
            ),
          ),
          TextField(
            controller: widget.passwordController,
            obscureText: true,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              labelText: "Password",
              hintText: "password",
              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
            ),
          ),
          Visibility(
            child: Container(
              child: Text(
                errorController.text,
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.red,
                ),
              ),
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
            ),
            visible: _isErrorContainerVisible,
          ),
          RaisedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              context.read<AuthenticationService>().signIn(
                  email: widget.emailController.text.trim(),
                  password: widget.passwordController.text.trim());
            },
            child: Text("Sign In"),
          ),
          RaisedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
                  return SignUp(widget.emailController.text.trim().toString(),
                      widget.passwordController.text.trim().toString());
                }),
              );
            },
            child: Text("Sign Up"),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Basically what I am trying to do is display the Text in the `Visibility` widget if `errorText` inside the `AuthenticationService` has an error (because a user failed to login). The problem I am realizing is that the signIn method is a Future and so the error isn't going to be set immediately (I'm thinking I need some sort of listener for the variable). I've followed some examples [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/forms/text-field-changes) that use `TextEditingController`, and this kinda works except I need to click the login button a second time to display the error instead of it coming up the first time. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up figuring out the answer and want to share in case someone else needs help.

Basically, I needed to have my `AuthenticationHelper` class extend a `ChangeNotifier` which allowed me to call `notifyListeners()` when any firebase auth exception occured.

Next, I needed to use the Provider library to create a `context.select`([documentation](https://pub.dev/packages/provider)) which allowed me to watch for when that `notifyListeners()` is called. Once it detected that there was a change to the error text, I set the _isErrorContainerVisible to true and the error is displayed.